# iptables and hacker prevention

Tags: networking, server, ssh, iptables, firewall

Hello fellow Ubuntuers!

here is an example of my iptables.rules file:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:f2b-sshd - [0:0]
:f2b-sshd-ddos - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd-ddos
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -s 202.215.160.75/32 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 66.210.251.136/32 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 61.40.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd-ddos
-A INPUT -i tap0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
-A f2b-sshd-ddos -j RETURN
COMMIT
```

note that this is a condensed version of my file. I probably have about 100 or so IPs/domains that I am dropping.

My problem is that when I drop a new ip like x.x.x.x, it adds it as follows:

```
-A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/32 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

This somehow then isnt actually dropping the ip address like I want it to. I have a shell script that I use to drop users/domains:

./drop-user

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s $1 -j DROP
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"
```

./drop-domain

```
 sudo iptables -A INPUT -s $1/16 -j DROP
 sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"
```

To combat this problem I am manually editing the /etc/iptables.rules files to move the x.x.x.x ip above this line:

```
 -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd-ddos
```

and then calling:

```
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

What is wrong with my process if anything? Is there a better way? Each day I spent about 10 mins dealing with hacks and most of that time is doing the editing of my iptables.rules files and then restoring it via iptables-restore. I would like to be able to just call ./drop-user or ./drop-domain and be done with it but I feel that I don't have enough of an understanding of iptables.

Should I be doing the following commands before the iptables-restore?

```
 sudo iptables -F
 sudo iptables -Z
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly urge you to automate the banning process with `fail2ban`, which works perfectly well in a default configuration and can be customized further if you want it to monitor more services.

When combined with `iptables-persistent`, it will preserve rules across reboots which is helpful.

Here is a basic overview of what I do with any Ubuntu server:

#### Install and configure fail2ban

```
sudo aptitude install fail2ban && sudo cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local && sudo nano /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

This installs it and copies the configuration file to a new file for your customizations. This is best practice because it prevents your edits from being overwritten if the package is updated.

My personal preference is to extend the *ban time* and *find time* from the defaults. Ban time is how long an attacker is banned for, and find time is the window of time their attempts are counted, in case they rate limit attacks. Find and edit `bantime = 21600` (increased to six hours, time value is in seconds) and also `findtime = 3600` (max 3 attack attempts per hour).

#### Flush existing Iptables rules and set new defaults

This is a one-liner that is meant to be used on a typical web server with inbound ports listening on port 22 (SSH) port 80 (HTTP) and port 443 (HTTPS) only. [This DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04) is a good reference for how to build your own or customize mine. **Be careful with Iptables and setting DROP rules, if you get the order wrong you will permanently lock yourself out!** That said, this one-liner is what I use and it is safe, tested, and working perfectly:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT && sudo iptables -F && sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT && sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT && sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT && sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT && sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT && sudo iptables -A INPUT -j LOG && sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG && sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -j LOG && sudo ip6tables -A FORWARD -j LOG && sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

#### Make changes persistent across reboots

Last step is to install and configure the `iptables-persistent` package, which will automate saving and restoring rules across reboots.

```
sudo aptitude install iptables-persistent && sudo service iptables-persistent start
```

It will prompt you for confirmation for IPV4 and IPV6 rules, and you should use the tab key to select 'yes' for each and save. It will start automatically when rebooting so you don't need to worry about configuring it further.

One thing to note about making the rules persistent is that you need to manually tell the process about any new rules you add or edit (like if you added or removed HTTPS on port 443 for example). To do this, run `sudo service iptables-persistent save` which will update the current set of rules in place. I think the command was changed to "netfilter-persistent" in versions later than 14.04 so use `sudo service netfilter-persistent save` if the first one does not work.

#### Summary

Now fail2ban will monitor attacks on SSH and add and subtract IP addresses automatically according to the parameters you set. Iptables will ignore all incoming traffic for ports you haven't opened and these rules will persist across reboots, so there isn't much else you need to do. Enjoy the extra free time I guess!

#### Reversing all the above steps if you wish to undo all changes

If for some reason you don't want to continue using this method, you can undo everything quickly. This is not recommended but it's your machine so here's how:

1. Flush all Iptables rules and accept all traffic on all ports `sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT && sudo iptables -F` (you must do this to remove the DROP rule at the end or you will be locked out)
2. Remove the previously installed packages and their settings `sudo aptitude purge fail2ban iptables-persistent` (or maybe `netfilter-persistent`, depending on your version of Ubuntu server).
   After a restart, you should be back to the way you were before - minus any custom Iptables settings which you will need to manually re-add like you are currently doing.

Comment: Tom, if you closely examine my iptables.rules file, you will see I am already using fail2ban. :) '-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
-A f2b-sshd-ddos -j RETURN'. In addition to f2b I want to permanently block hacking ips.

Comment: @PeterS Yes I see the `:f2b...` entries but I'm curious about your setup. In my default install the entries read `fail2ban-ssh...`. Have you made many customisations from the default config? It's prefectly fine to do this of course, but it makes diagnosing harder as you get further away from system defaults. You should also consider using [ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/index.html) for permanently banning lots of addresses as it will be more efficient (that's a far more complicated and different question though).

Comment: here are the changes I made in jail.conf: # "bantime" is the number of seconds that a host is banned.
bantime  = 600

# A host is banned if it has generated "maxretry" during the last "findtime"
# seconds.
findtime  = 600

# "maxretry" is the number of failures before a host get banned.
maxretry = 5

Comment: I think the settings for the f2b names in iptables are here: /etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables.conf, but I didnt change this file or any others except for jail.conf

Comment: @PeterS With fail2ban, you copy the jail.conf & customize it, which takes priority over the defaults. The DO tutorials are pretty comprehensive so to help you get back on track, see [here for basic SSH](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04) or [here for how to create a custom one for WordPress](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-wordpress-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04) for example. You don't want to edit the wrong files and you want to automate everything so you aren't having to track IPs to add manually.